# Training and Validation Acuracy is not improving using datagen.flow_from_directory in google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, classification, conv-neural-network, data-generation

The CNN model will classify between two class with **training samples = 5974 and validation = 1987.**

I am using **datagen.flow_from_directory** and my model will **predict from separate test set**. **I am running the code For 200 epoch in Google Colab, but after 5 epoch, the training and validation accuracy is not improving.**

Accuracy

Epoch 45/200
186/186 [==============================] - 138s 744ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4983 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 46/200
186/186 [==============================] - 137s 737ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4990 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 47/200
186/186 [==============================] - 142s 761ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4987 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 48/200
186/186 [==============================] - 140s 752ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4993 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5005

Epoch 49/200
186/186 [==============================] - 139s 745ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4976 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5010

Epoch 50/200
186/186 [==============================] - 143s 768ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4992 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 51/200
186/186 [==============================] - 140s 755ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4980 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 52/200
186/186 [==============================] - 141s 758ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4990 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.4995

Epoch 53/200
186/186 [==============================] - 141s 759ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4985 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 54/200
186/186 [==============================] - 143s 771ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4987 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.4995

Epoch 55/200
186/186 [==============================] - 143s 771ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.4992 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5005

```
train_data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/snk_tod/train"
valid_data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/snk_tod/valid"
test_data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/snk_tod/test"


img_rows = 100
img_cols = 100
epochs = 200
print(epochs)
batch_size = 32

num_of_train_samples = 5974
num_of_valid_samples =  1987 


#Image Generator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                   rotation_range=40,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')


valid_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_path,
                                                    target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(valid_data_path,
                                                        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        shuffle=True,
                                                        class_mode='categorical')
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_data_path,
                                                        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
                                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        shuffle=False,
                                                        class_mode='categorical')

 model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D((32), (3, 3), input_shape=(img_rows, img_cols, 3), kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", bias_initializer="zeros"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D((32), (3, 3),kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", bias_initializer="zeros"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D((64), (3, 3),kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", bias_initializer="zeros"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D((64), (3, 3),kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform", bias_initializer="zeros"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(512))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['acc'])

#Train
history=model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=num_of_train_samples // batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps=num_of_valid_samples // batch_size)
```

Comment: What is the file structure of the train and test portions?

Comment: I have two separate folders : Training  and testing. Inside training I have two folder 'snake' and 'toad' . Also in testing folder, there are two separate folder  'snake' and 'toad' . is this what your are asking for?

Comment: Too many dropout layers. Remove all of them except the one after `Flatten`

Comment: Also change `sigmoid` to `softmax` if you want to use `categorical_crossentropy`. You're not suppose to make it run in the first place if sum of the output isn't 1. I'm really curious why it didn't error

Comment: Also you should place `Activation` after `BatchNormalization`

Comment: Thank you @NatthaphonHongcharoen I will try with the changes you suggested. 

About the sigmoid and SoftMax, it didn't show error because class_mode  was given 'categorical' instead of binary.